# Unable to retrieve the Cookie value using signedCookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cookies, mern

for verifying the cookie value i used a verifyToken function in which i first try to log the value of cookie using response.signedCookies but get undefined on my console.

```js
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { COOKIE_NAME } from "./constants.js";

export const verifyToken = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  const token = req.signedCookies[`${COOKIE_NAME}`] // Try to retrieve the value of cookie
  console.log(token);
};
```

But instead of getting token value i got undefined on my console. [here the screenshot of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hudyf.png)

I'm sending the cookie value from login controller and its signed also.

```js
export const userLogin = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).send("User not registered !");
    }
    const isPasswordCorrect = await compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isPasswordCorrect) {
      return res.status(403).send("Incorrect Password !!");
    }

    res.clearCookie(COOKIE_NAME, {
      httpOnly: true,
      path: "/",
      domain: "localhost",
      signed: true,
    });

    const token = createToken(user._id.toString(), user.email, "7d");
    const expires = new Date();
    expires.setDate(expires.getDate() + 7);
    res.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, token, {
      path: "/",
      domain: "localhost",
      expires,
      httpOnly: true,
      signed: true,
    });

    return res
      .status(200)
      .json({ message: "OK", name: user.name, email: user.email });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    return res.status(200).json({ message: "ERROR", cause: error.message });
  }
};
```

Here the screenshot of response [I'm getting on my browser networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igsPM.png) Here when i click on set cookie header the dialogue box appears saying "This attempt to set a cookie was blocked due to user preferences"

Comment: The cookie is valid for the hostname `localhost`, but according to the browser address bar, you accessed the whole thing via `127.0.0.1` instead - so that probably has something to do with it.

Comment: @CBroe if i change this in axios which is app.use(cors({ origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5173", credentials: true }));...if replace 127.0.0.1 with localhost i got CORS error and if replaced the localhost with 127.0.0.1 in my userlogin function then in the network section of browser inside the set-cookie tag i get "this attempt to set a cookie via set-cookie header is blocked because its domain attribute was invalid"